# Como imprimir un ArrayList completo en la consola de c#

Tags: c#, lista, arraylist, terminal

estoy tratando de imprimir un Arraylist de una clase que ya tiene todos los datos guardados, necesito que este me imprima todos los datos de esta ArrayList y poder agregar un nuevo parametro.
estoy intentando crear un programa de curriculum en consola de C# y se me a complicado este paso.
Quiero que se pueda ver el ArrayList y que se pueda evaluar con un parametro de aceptar o rechazar para luego mostrar en otra apartado.
dejo code de referencia.

```
static private void CExistente(ArrayList Ainfo) //Curriculim existentes
        {
            int fila_1 = 9;
            int iD = 1;
            foreach (Informacion p in Ainfo)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(15, fila_1); Console.Write("#: " + iD.ToString());
                Console.SetCursorPosition(15, fila_1+1); Console.Write("Nombre: " + p.getNombre());
                Console.SetCursorPosition(15, fila_1+2); Console.Write("Puesto Aspirado:" + p.getPuesto());

                Console.SetCursorPosition(15, fila_1+3); Console.Write("════════════════════════════════");

                fila_1 += 4;
                iD++;
            }
            
        }
public static void Evaluar(ArrayList Ainfo, Informacion info) //Funcion para evaluar el curriculum del empleado si aceptar o rechazar
        {
            limpia(1, 79, 8, 20);
            CExistente(Ainfo);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 22); Console.Write("Id del curriculum que desea analizar: ");

            int seleccion = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (seleccion - 1 > Ainfo.Count)
            {
                limpia(0, 79, 8, 20);
                Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 15); Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.Write("EL CURRICULUM INDICADO NO EXISTE");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 20); Console.WriteLine("Presione una tecla para continuar...");
                return;
            }
            if (seleccion - 1 < 0)
            {
                limpia(0, 79, 8, 20);
                Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 15); Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.Write("EL CURRICULUM INDICADO NO EXISTE");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 20); Console.WriteLine("Presione una tecla para continuar...");
                Console.ResetColor();
            
            }
            Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 19); Console.WriteLine("Opciones para aceptar o rechazar el curriculum");// Estas son las opciones para aceptar o rechazar 
            Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 20); Console.WriteLine("Digite si la Opcion es Aceptar o Rechazar A/R ");
            string op_veri = (Console.ReadLine()).ToUpper();
            switch (op_veri)
            {
                case "A":
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 8); Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green; Console.WriteLine("su informacion a sido agregada.");
                    Ainfo.Add(info);
                    break;
                case "R":
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(15, 8); Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.WriteLine("su informacion a sido rechazada.");
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Hola  Dec-SOM, bienvenido, te sugiero que hagas el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: No entendí el problema, puedes explicarlo de otra forma??? Ojalá con un ejemplo de salida. Por otro lado debes preferir usar `List` en vez de `ArrayList`

Comment: No entiendo lo que tratas de decir, edita tu pregunta y explicate mejor para que se te pueda ayudar